# Is a vendor also a maintenance worker?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I know this question sounds weird, but here's the information.
I got an email from my apartment.

> Dear Valued Residents,
>
> Our **vendor** will be on-site tomorrow, Tuesday, April 25, 2017 to complete dryer vent cleaning for the entire community between the hours of 8 am to 6 pm.
>
> No access inside your homes will be needed. Our **vendor** will be completing this service through the exterior vents in each building.

To me, a vendor means a person who sells on the street. But in this email, it seems a vendor means a person who maintains our dryer vent.

Is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of our site is that you have attempted some research on your own; for example, looking up *[vendor](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vendor?q=vendor)* in the OALD provides a meaning of *a company that sells a particular product*. If the building contracts out its dryer vent maintenance to an outside firm, then that firm is indeed a *vendor*.

Comment: @choster A service is not a product. IMHO, if the building contracts out its maintenance to an outside firm, then that firm is a ***contractor***.

Comment: @michael.hor257k *Contractor* in reference to physical plant in the U.S. usually refers to construction and infrastructure engineering; I wouldn't refer to the companies that provide security, housekeeping, window washing, and so on as *contractors* outside of legal/contractual contexts.

Comment: in the world of independent contractors (any freelance work of any kind at all [I know, I am one: editor and translator]), a vendor and a contractor are the same thing. But here, they should have just our service provider or servicing company. Vendor was a bad choice of word here.

Answer (score 0):

A [vendor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor) can also be a contracted service provider.

From wikipedia:

> In a supply chain, a vendor, or a seller, is an enterprise that contributes goods or services. Generally, a supply chain vendor manufactures inventory/stock items and sells them to the next link in the chain. Today, the terms refers to a supplier of any good or service.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused at first, cause I thought it has some relations with the verb vent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe ***vendor*** here has anything to do with ***vent***. It is simply a coincidence that the normal word meaning "seller" is so close in sound to "vent" - a part of the equipment they have sold. ***Vendor*** simply refers to the firm who has sold the equipment.

However, I wouldn't have written it like that, nor would I expect to see it written like that in Britain. Had I written the announcement I would have said

***"The vendor's engineer will be here tomorrow to carry out cleaning of vents..."***